# List of mathematical symbols and their associated commands

Tags: symbols

I am trying to find the list of mathematical symbols and their associated commands provided by Latex.  But having difficulty finding what the right document for this kind of information in the Latex Website.

Comment: Have fun with the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: You can search for "latex cheat sheet" to find several short documents. The [comprehensive list](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) is over 400 pages long, but is searchable and has a good table of contents and index. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cheat-sheet) has several cheat sheets as well.

Comment: Quite long as you say with many packages printing the same symbols.

Comment: Still, the Help page of the Latex Project is too convoluted for normal folks to find what they need.  Extremely Complicated.  And still cannot find the way to navigate towards the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List.  How is it located somewhere completely different than the Latex Project !

Comment: The latex project is not responsible for any of the symbols in that list, so it should not be surprising that the file is hosted elsewhere, but as all the documentation from whatever original source is installed locally on your machine and you just need `texdoc symbols` it doesn't really matter who maintains that document.

Comment: Would that be Texlive related ?